# Maintain horizontal position of a "position: fixed" div when resizing window

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a two column website with a right sided column that changes to a fixed position when scrolling. 
This is the css:

```
#sidebar {
padding: 5px;
width: 200px;
float: left;
background-color: yellow;
}

.fixed {
position: fixed;
padding: 5px;
background-color: yellow;
}

.span8 {
padding: 5px;
width: 400px;
float: left;
background-color: blue;
}
```

This is the javascript:
    var position = $('#sidebar').position();
        var offset = $("#sidebar").offset();

```
    $(window).scroll(function() {          

        if ($(window).scrollTop() > offset.top) {
            $('#sidebar').addClass('fixed');
            $('.fixed').css("top", 0);  
            $('.fixed').css("left", position.left);
         } 

        else {
            $('#sidebar').removeClass('fixed');

        }


    });
```

And here is the html:

## Large header

```
<div class="span8">
  <h4>This is the main column</h4>
  <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod    tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.<p>
</div>
<div id="sidebar">
  <h4>Hello!</h4>
  <p>This is a fixed a fixed sidebar on scroll</p>
</div>
```

This all works fine, see jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LennartJagt/MAKYb/2/ the only problem is that when a user re-sizes the window the sidebar stays on its original horizontal position. I can't figure out how to make this work on resizing.

The annoying thing is that jsfiddle makes it look perfect but in a browser without jsfiddle it doesn't work. Any help would be much appriciated!

Lennart

Comment: Did you try to catch the `resize` event, and call `scrollIntoView(true)` on your `span8` element ?

Answer (score 0):

Wasn't able to reproduce your issue, for me it works. But it does blink and disappear occasionally.

Some suggestions:

1) Why not go pure CSS? This, without any javascript, works perfectly for me:

```
#sidebar {
padding: 5px;
width: 200px;
background-color: yellow;
position:relative;
left:410px;
top:0;
}


.span8 {
padding: 5px;
width: 400px;
float: left;
background-color: blue;
position:absolute;
}
```

2) What you have here:

```
$('.fixed').css("left", position.left);
```

will only work if position.left is 0. To make it work at all times, specify that it's in pixels, like this:

```
$('.fixed').css("left", position.left + "px");
```

3) This is completely untested, but assuming that your original code works for you, maybe this would work. Simply: wrap your positioning code into a function, and then call this function both on window scroll and window resize events:

```
function positionSidebar() {
    var position = $('#sidebar').position();
    var offset = $("#sidebar").offset();    

    if ($(window).scrollTop() > offset.top) {
        $('#sidebar').css('fixed');  
        $('#sidebar').css("left", position.left);
     } 

    else {
        $('#sidebar').removeClass('fixed');
    }       
}

$(window).scroll(function() {         
    positionSidebar();
}); 

$(window).resize(function() {         
    positionSidebar();
});
```

Comment: Tried your third option and it works but flickers like crazy, gonna try your first but don't know if it works in my actual website (which is a bit more complex than the jsfiddle example) did help me out allready though, thanx!

Comment: First one should be the simplest and most reliable.